# Cropit How to call or execute a function after file selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, crop

Hi i'm using the following plugin 
[CropIt](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/), in order to work with the images on my website, in the documentation there is an option called **"onFileChange"** but the documentation itself isn't really helpful, i need to execute a function right after the user selects an image from the dialog box.

Not sure how to do it with that as the image always gets loaded on the background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set it as an option param. Example:

```
$('#image-cropper').cropit(
    {
        onFileChange: function() {
            alert('Change test');
        }
    }
);
```